# jquery not correctly picking selected value of dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

The issue is that Jquery is not picking the selected value of the dropdown correctly. It is picking the value which is selected at the time of page loading .. A small code example is as under:

```
 $.trim($("#abc option:selected").text())
```

but it seems to always pick the values which was selected earlier when the page was loaded. . There are also other dropdowns which seem to be bahving similarly.

Kind regards,

Comment: when do you call this method? can you show us how this is called?

Comment: the values are collected when a button is clicked. the button verifies the other entered data and then calls a method to collect these values: (MVC code portion as under)

 if (valid) {
            SaveUserPreference('url')')
        }

Comment: something like this? maybe it can help you out: http://www.codegateway.com/2012/03/get-dropdownlist-selected-value-in.html

Comment: have seen this page :) .. the issue is not picking up the text but it is that the code is picking values which was selected at page load and does not seem to get the value which is later changed via mouse/keyboard

Comment: I suppose you've tried leaving out trim? and you've also tried getting the val?

Comment: In other dropdowns, it also seems to doing the same (where val is used) e.g.
$("#xyz").val();  -- it is picking the value which was selected at page load and does not seem to pick the value if changed by the user.

Comment: Apologies.. The code for picking up the values was written outside of the function that is probably why it executed when the page loaded. :)
Thank you for the time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for picking up the values was written outside of the function that is probably why it executed when the page loaded. :)